# Как удалить несколько коммитов на github.com?

Tags: github

Собственно вопрос указан в теме. Можно ли удалить несколько последних коммитов через веб интерфейс github.com?

Если нет, то как вообще делаются откаты к предыдущим версиям через github.com?

Comment: @koks_rs, вам нужно начисто удалить какие-то вещи из репозитория, или откатить локально некоторое количество правок?

Comment: Нужно локально откатится до определенной версии. Для этого создал отдельную ветку, но не могу разобраться как откатиться назад. 
Либо же возможно сделать ответвление прямо из нужного мне коммита?

Answer (score 1):

> Нужно локально откатится до определенной версии.

`git checkout abc098`, где `abc098`- первые шесть символов SHA-хэша коммита. Также можно использовать ссылку `HEAD~N`, где N - количество коммитов, на которые надо откатиться, например `git checkout HEAD~2` "отойдет" на два коммита назад. `git log` поможет найти SHA коммитов.

> Либо же возможно сделать ответвление прямо из нужного мне коммита?

Интернет рассказал мне о такой конструкции

```
git checkout -b old-state 0d1d7fc32
```

где 0d1d7fc32, понятное дело, SHA нужного коммита, а old-state - название ветки